# How to configure IP filtering at DIGI Passport Terminal Server

Tags: networking, terminal-server

Currenntly I am only allowing 1 IP address to access HTTPS service from my DIGI. It is shown as below for example:

invert 10.0.0.3/255.255.255.255 HTTPS DROP

The problem is that I would like to give access to let say 2 to 3 more hosts which are for example 10.0.0.4/24 and 10.0.0.10/24. I have no idea on how to do it and the DIGI manual example does not explain much about it.

Please kindly assist.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://ftp1.digi.com/support/documentation/90000767_D.pdf page 248 seems to explain how to do it, you need to add the IPs to the IP filtering page.